# why is named import not sufficient for importing an exported constant

Tags: javascript, vite

I'm rewriting an old code base and some basic javascript is not working on the new code base the way it did on the old. I have an array (memstatNames) in a file `checkboxes/checkboxes`, and I'm importing it in another file like this

`import { memstatNames } from '../checkboxes/checkboxes'` but the interpreter (I'm using vite) is telling me that checkboxes doesn't provide an export called `memstatNames.` In my old code base, that import worked fine. It is a named import.

```
export const memstatNames: Array<MemstatName> = [
{
  name: 'Alloc',
  checked: false
},
{
  name: 'TotalAlloc',
  checked: false
}]

export interface MemstatName {
  name: string;
  checked: boolean;
}
```

Comment: The same code works well in my machine. Make sure have spelled correctly when importing.